# angularjs ng-show can't hide

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I'm kinda new to angular so this may be a dumb question but I have this snippet of code:

```
              <tr ng-repeat="ingr in recipe.ingredients">
                <div ng-show="ingr.edit">
                    <td>{{ ingr.amount }}</td>
                    <!--td>{{ ingr.units }}</td> -->
                    <td>{{ingr.edit}}</td> //here I see ingr.edit toggle
                    <td>{{ ingr.description }}</td>
                </div>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ingr.edit = !ingr.edit">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                    </button> 
                </td>

              </tr>
```

but I can't hide the div. I can see in one of the table cells that ingr.edit toggles correctly, but still the div is always visible.

Can someone help?
thanks

Comment: Do you see `false` in your `{{ingr.edit}}`? Can you try with `ng-if` instead?

Comment: Invalid HTML. A `<tr>` can only contain children that are `<td>`.

Comment: add ng-show to table not on div, and use td as wrapper for that table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this ?

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.recipe = {ingredients:[{
     amount:10,edit:true,description:"foo"},//edit:true or it won't ever show in my sample
    {amount:50,edit:true,description:"bar"}]};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="app"  ng-controller="ctrl">
 <tr ng-repeat="ingr in recipe.ingredients" ng-show="ingr.edit">

     <td>{{ ingr.amount }}</td>
     <!--td>{{ ingr.units }}</td> -->
     <td>{{ingr.edit}}</td> //here I see ingr.edit toggle
     <td>{{ ingr.description }}</td>

   <td>
     <button type="button" ng-click="ingr.edit = !ingr.edit">
       CLICK
     </button> 
   </td>

</tr>
```

I moved the `ng-show` in the `<tr>` because `<div>` tag is invalid there so it will have been totally ignored.

EDIT : see@sag Answer to see how to replace the div tag by a table so it will get executed.

Comment: The only issue with this is that once the `ingr.edit` is toggled to false, there is no way to toggle it back to true. Presumably the OP left out a good deal of HTML where some type of edit controls will be shown and hidden. I think the `ng-show` would be best moved to those individual edit controls, but this is just a SWAG as the original question does not give a clear indication of the overall desired functionality.

Comment: @Lex yes that's why i answered this, i answer on the technical part of what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <tr ng-repeat="ingr in recipe.ingredients">
           <td>
             <table ng-show="ingr.edit">
                <td>{{ ingr.amount }}</td>
                <!--td>{{ ingr.units }}</td> -->
                <td>{{ingr.edit}}</td> //here I see ingr.edit toggle
                <td>{{ ingr.description }}</td>
             </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ingr.edit = !ingr.edit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </button> 
            </td>

          </tr>
```

Include table not div, you can't add div directly on tr

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow
the code can be modified to:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-hide="ingr.edit"> 
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>                    
</button>
```

The development still depends on `{{ingr}}`.